# Vaadin: How to bind entity "meta data"

Tags: data-binding, entity, vaadin

I'm tring to figure out how to bind meta data about an entity that's not an actual field in the entity. For example, consider the following:

```
Task:
    title: string
    description: string
    ...
    notes: List<TaskNote>
```

I'd like to be able to display the `Task` in a grid, or in an "editor" form and display, say the count of `TaskNote`s associated with a `Task`. So, in this case, the count is simply the number of items in the `notes` list.

How do I create a data binding for something like this? What are the best practices/techniques?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I'm asking what are the best ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, your question is too open ended to qualify an answer by StackOverflow code of conduct. E.g. do you want to bind List of Tasks or just a Task. However, there is a good set of training material on Vaadin pages, see https://vaadin.com/learn/training/v14-forms and https://vaadin.com/learn/training/v14-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Binder is used for binding `Fields` into a specific bean's `Properties`. A `Person` bean could have the `Properties` "first name", "last name" and "birth year". However, `Field` and `Property` are quite abstract concepts, leaving you a lot of room to maneuver.

- A `Field` is something, typically a `Component`, that implements the `HasValue` interface. The `HasValue` interface (and thus the `Field`) has a Java type, such as `String`.
- A `Property` is essentially a getter/setter pair. The pair must have a matching type - the getter's return type must match what the setter takes as an input.

  - The `Property`'s getter can be provided by implementing the `ValueProvider` functional interface, which, in a simple form, can be a Lambda expression such as `person -> person.getFirstName()`
  - the setter can be provided with an implementation of the `Setter` functional interface. A simple example as a Lambda would be `(person, newFirstName) -> person.setFirstName(newFirstName)`.

When you create a `Binder`, you provide the `ValueProvider` and `Setter` in one way or another; the most explicit way would be when you're binding like this:

```
Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>();
TextField firstNameField = new TextField("First name");
binder.forField(firstNameField).bind(valueProvider, setter);
```

When you're dealing with something that is a part of a bean, but not a `Property`, you have a couple of different options. For example, the Person's "age" can be calculated as a function of their "birth year". Let's say we only want to be able to edit the birth year, but we also want to display the age as a read-only value. It could also be a discount percentage based on age or something.

The first, easiest approach is to use a `Field`, but only with a `ValueProvider` and no `Setter`. So you could have something like this (using `TextField` for simplicity):

```java
Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>();
TextField ageField = new TextField("Age (calculated)");
binder.forField(ageField).bind(person -> calculateAge(person.getBirthYear()), null);
```

The downside of this approach is that you're still using a `TextField`, which is an editor component. You can set it to read-only mode so the user can't change the value, but it still *looks* like you might be able to edit it at some point.

Another thing you can use is a `ReadOnlyHasValue`, which is an interface for creating a `Property` without a `Setter`. It's a bit clunky, but you can use it with binding:

```java
Span ageDisplay = new Span();
ReadOnlyHasValue<String> ageField = new ReadOnlyHasValue<>(text -> ageDisplay.setText(text));
binder.forField(ageField).bind(person -> calculateAge(person.getBirthYear()), null);
```

Finally, as `ValueProvider` and `Setter` are just Java interfaces, you can implement them with any kinds of side effects that you might want. So you can piggyback any logic to a Property's changes:

```java
Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>();
Span ageDisplay = new Span();
TextField birthYear = new TextField();
binder.forField(birthYear)
  .bind(person -> { // ValueProvider
    return person.getBirthYear();
  }, (person, newBirthYear) -> { // Setter
    person.setBirthYear(newBirthYear);
    ageDisplay.setText(calculateAge(newBirthYear));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will try some of these suggestions out and let you know how it goes.